# How to execute a js function every time a change occurs in a DOM tag?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tinymce

I have the tinymce plugin in a form, the thing is that the form is created dynamically as a certain condition is met and the tinymce container is created and deleted continuously.

I get this error in the console:

```
tinymce.js:25473 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
    at initContentBody (tinymce.js:25473)
    at init$1 (tinymce.js:25610)
    at init$2 (tinymce.js:25723)
    at Editor.<anonymous> (tinymce.js:25841)
    at Array.<anonymous> (tinymce.js:7470)
    at each$2 (tinymce.js:2585)
    at loadScripts (tinymce.js:7467)
    at tinymce.js:7454
    at HTMLScriptElement.done (tinymce.js:7362)
```

I suppose it is because tinymce does not know where it should start, but I am not sure which event could solve this problem according to my structure.

This is my form:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
   $type = $_POST['type'];
} else {
   $type= '1';
}

switch ($tipo) {
 case '1': ?>
   <form>
   <!-- content for 1 -->
   <textarea id="text1" class="editor" cols="55" rows="20" require"></textarea>
   </form> <?php
   break;

 case '2': ?>
   <form>
   <!-- content for 2 -->
   <textarea id="text2" class="editor" cols="55" rows="20" require"></textarea>
   </form> <?php
   break;

 case '3': ?>
   <form>
   <!-- content for 3 -->
   <textarea id="text3" class="editor" cols="55" rows="20" require"></textarea>
   </form> <?php
   break;
  
 default:
   # code...
   break;
}
?>
```

the variable `$_POST ['type']` is sent by ajax when buttons are clicked to change the form. If you know how to solve this problem, I would appreciate your answer. The tinymce is loaded in the textarea with the editor class.

If you need any other information, ask me. Thanks a lot.

PROGRESS MADE:

I managed to find a way for javascript to watch for changes in the DOM and run the tinymce setting every time there are changes:

```
var observeDOM = (function(){
  var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver, eventListenerSupported = window.addEventListener;
  return function(obj, callback){
      if( MutationObserver )
  { // define a new observer

var obs = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer){
  if( mutations[0].addedNodes.length || mutations[0].removedNodes.length ) callback();
}); // have the observer observe foo for changes in children

obs.observe( obj, { childList:true, subtree:true });
} else if( eventListenerSupported ){ obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', callback, false); obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', callback, false); } } })(); // Observe a specific dom element:

observeDOM( document.getElementById('formCrear') ,function(){ 
  // console.log('dom changed');
  iniciar();
});

function iniciar() {
  tinymce.init({
    selector: ".editor",  // change this value according to your HTML
    language: "es",
    encoding: "UTF-8",
    entity_encoding: "raw",
    plugins: [
      'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker',
      'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
      'table template paste codesample'
    ],
    toolbar: 'styleselect | bold italic underline removeformat | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | ' +
      'bullist numlist outdent indent | link image media codesample',
    menubar: 'file edit view insert tools table',
    menu: {
      file: { title: 'File', items: 'newdocument | print' },
      edit: { title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste | selectall | searchreplace' },
      view: { title: 'View', items: 'visualaid visualchars visualblocks | preview fullscreen' },
      insert: { title: 'Insert', items: 'charmap hr | pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc | insertdatetime' },
      table: { title: 'Table', items: 'inserttable | cell row column | tableprops deletetable' }
    },
    style_formats_merge: true,
    statusbar: false,
    width : '100%',
    height : '380',
  });
}
```

Tinymce displays correctly at first, the problem is that if I activate the first form, then the second and then return to the first, it no longer activates. That is, it is activated only the first time the form is created, if it is changed to another and then returns to the one previously shown, it no longer appears until the page is reloaded.

Comment: You need to show how you're configuring TinyMCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I solved it this way: I had to add the mutationobserver in the two files of the tinymce, so that it reads them continuously whenever an action is fulfilled, the change is observed in the DOM and then it reads the data of the function that contains the data for tinymce to work.

```
init();
$('.listBlog a').on('click', function(){
  var observeDOM = (function(){
    var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver, eventListenerSupported = window.addEventListener;
    return function(obj, callback){
        if( MutationObserver ) { // define a new observer
  
      var obs = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer){
        if( mutations[0].addedNodes.length || mutations[0].removedNodes.length )
        callback();
        obs.disconnect();
      }); // have the observer observe foo for changes in children
      
      obs.observe( obj, { childList:true, subtree:true });
      } else if ( eventListenerSupported ){
        obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', callback, false);
        obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', callback, false);
      }  
    }
  })(); // Observe a specific dom element:

  observeDOM( document.getElementById('formCrear') ,function(){ 
    // console.log('dom changed');
    init();
  });
  
});

function init() {
// data of custom.tinymce.js
}
```

And the same but in the file `tinymce.min.js`